# Regex to match only the second ip address in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match only the second valid ip address in a string with a range of ip addresses. Sometimes it's written without a space between addresses and something it has one or more spaces. Also sometimes the ip isn't valid so it shouldn't match.

```
test = '''
1.0.0.0-1.0.0.240
2.0.0.0 - 1.0.0.241
3.0.0.0 -1.0.0.242
4.0.0.0- 1.0.0.243
5.0.0.0  -  1.0.0.244
6.0.0.0 -  1.0.0.245
7.0.0.0 -  1.0.0.2456 #NOT VALID SO DONT MATCH
'''

pattern = r"(?<=-\s))\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
r = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)
print(r.findall(test))
```

My try only catches: 1.0.0.241 and 1.0.0.243

Comment: Another idea with [capture](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall): [`re.findall(r"- *((?:\d{1,3}\.?\b){4})", test)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurJLW4RMFWQV1dnctQzwAEdSG0kYkBlxFEREFXASZmyGUME4MJGXGZQDXCVRlzmUJVAbXCRU24zODmwQVNucyxCJopKPv5hyiEOfp4uigE@yu4@PuFKPg6hjh7cIFcylVQlJlXolGUqpeWmZeSmJOjUaSkq6CloWFvFZNSbahjXBujZx@TpFltUquppKMA8qOm5v//AA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change regex pattern to the following:

```
pattern = r"(?<=[-\s])((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})$"
r = re.compile(pattern, re.M)
print(r.findall(test))
```

---

- `(?<=[-\s])` - lookbehind assertion to match either `-` or `\s` as a boundary before IP address (which is enough in your case)
- `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}` - matches the 3 first octets each followed by `.` of IP address
- `$` - matches the end of the string in a multi-lined text (recognized by `re.M`)

---

```
['1.0.0.240', '1.0.0.241', '1.0.0.242', '1.0.0.243', '1.0.0.244', '1.0.0.245']
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation about re.M and your use of brackets [-\s]

Comment: @suzkirch, see my explanation

Answer (score 2):

All 4 existing answers are about regex, so I think you might find it interesting to have a 5th one which uses a built-in library: [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html). There's no point in reinventing the wheel, especially when the pre-made wheel is within your arms' reach.

Split each line by `-`, then try to parse the latter part. If there is a `ValueError`, we skip. Otherwise, append it to the list and continue:

```py
from ipaddress import IPv4Address

def get_last_of_ranges_from_text(text):
  lines = text.strip().splitlines()
  last_of_ranges = []
    
  for line in lines:
    _, last = line.split('-')
    
    try:
      last_ip = IPv4Address(last.strip())
    except ValueError:
      pass
    else:
      last_of_ranges.append(last_ip)

  return last_of_ranges
```

For the following text:

```
1.0.0.0-1.0.0.240
2.0.0.0 - 1.0.0.241
3.0.0.0 -1.0.0.242
4.0.0.0- 1.0.0.243
5.0.0.0  -  1.0.0.244
6.0.0.0 -  1.0.0.245
7.0.0.0 -  1.0.0.2456
```

...it outputs:

```py
[
  IPv4Address('1.0.0.240'), IPv4Address('1.0.0.241'), IPv4Address('1.0.0.242'),
  IPv4Address('1.0.0.243'), IPv4Address('1.0.0.244'), IPv4Address('1.0.0.245')
]
```

Neat, doesn't it? As a bonus, these `IPv4Address`es also support comparison operators:

```py
first_ip < last_ip
```

I'm sure you know what to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could have other text following the second IP (not just the end of the line), you could change the last part to add a negative lookahead for 4 consecutive digits.  To get the second IP, your approach seems to be based on the presence of a delimiter formed of spaces and dashes sot you can use a lookbehind for one of those preceding the IP address:

```
(?<=[ -])(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}(?!\d{4})\d{1,3}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should match all your examples:

```
pattern = r"^.*\s*-\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})$"
r = re.compile(pattern)
print(r.findall(test))
```

You can also just get the second IP by using the group function.

Answer (score 1):

```
test = '''
1.0.0.0-1.0.0.240
2.0.0.0 - 1.0.0.241
3.0.0.0 -1.0.0.242
4.0.0.0- 1.0.0.243
5.0.0.0  -  1.0.0.244
6.0.0.0 -  1.0.0.245
7.0.0.0 -  1.0.0.2456 #NOT VALID SO DONT MATCH
'''

pattern = r"(?<=-\s))\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
r = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)
print(r.findall(test))
```

Your zero-length assertion requires two characters: dash followed by white-space characters, your example suggest you want dash or space character which might be expressed as `-|`  additionally in order to avoid false positive word boundary `\b` might be used

```
import re
...
found = re.findall(r"(?<=-| )\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", test)
print(found)
```

gives output

```
['1.0.0.240', '1.0.0.241', '1.0.0.242', '1.0.0.243', '1.0.0.244', '1.0.0.245']
```